# Posets whose homotopy type can be efficiently studied without fibrant replacement?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, combinatorial-topology

Let $P$ be a poset and $NP$ its nerve. In order to study the homotopy type of $NP$ via the tools of simplicial homotopy theory, we generally need to take a Kan-fibrant replacement of $NP$, e.g. by applying the $Ex^\infty$ functor to $NP$. For instance, if we want to compute the homotopy groups of $NP$, this step is necessary in general.

However, there are some cases where the homotopy type of $NP$ can be detected without having to think about the fibrant replacement. Notably, [a number of commonly-encountered categorical properties imply that $NP$ is weakly contractible](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Eomar/notes/contractible.html). In a different vein, if $P$ is [shellable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelling_(topology)), then after quotienting some contractible, downward-closed sub-poset $Q$, one can find generators for the homology of $P$ given by single simplices in $P/Q$, a feature which generally can only be arranged for after fibrant replacement. Moreover, being shellable implies that $NP$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres, so understanding the homology gives complete information about the homotopy type of $P$.

I'm wondering if there are other settings akin to shellable posets, where the homotopy type can be understood in a similarly direct way, without fibrant replacement.

**Broad Question:** Are there other classes of posets $P$ whose homotopy type can be studied effectively without resorting to taking a fibrant replacement of $NP$?

**Narrower Question:** Are there interesting examples of non-shellable posets $P$ such that, possibly after quotienting by a contractible, downward-closed subposet $Q$, the homology of $P$ is generated by cycles $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that each $x_i$ is supported on a single simplex?

**Naive Question:** Are there other classes of posets besides shellable ones which tend to have the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres?

**Note:** I'd be interested in answers to these questions which talk about more general simplicial sets / simplicial complexes than just those coming from posets.

Comment: My feeling is people who do poset topology almost never take fibrant replacements. They use Quillen’s theorem A, nerve lemmas, Rita’s crosscut theorem, Galois connections and other tools like Cohen-Macaulay.  Bjorner and Wachs both have survey articles that give a sense.  They also use discrete Morse theory

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: *Rota's crosscut theorem

Comment: @SamHopkins, apparently iPhone only knows Rita and not Rota

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no need to restrict to a certain class of objects to understand homotopy theory of simplicial sets or of (nerves of) small categories without talking fibrant replacements. Quillen's theorems A and B (and their numerous variants) are indeed ways to work without taking fibrant replacements rather efficiently (even with general simplicial sets).

Comment: For instance, a useful trick to detect that a simplicial set $X$ is weakly contractible is that, for any finite poset $P$, any map $P\to X$ is connected through a finite zig zag of simplicial homotopies to a constant map. Thomason's description of homotopy colimits of functors with values in the category of categories in terms of Grothendieck constructions is quite useful (this is a variation on Quillen's theorem A). Theorem B and its variants also give ways to produce homotopy pullbacks without ever mentioning (Kan) fibrations.